# Adding a 2016 engineers survey to the sidebar

Tags: discussion, feature-request

StackOverflow has a "2016 Developer Survey" going on right now host by surveymonkey.  It is full of various questions that relate to daily life as a programmer or whoever is visiting StackOverflow.

Could we get one of those put on the sidebar of the EE.SE site?  It'd be really interesting to know what kind of things the electrical engineers here deal with on a daily basis and such.

Comment: I don't think we have a large enough user base to have meaningful results.

Comment: There's only one way to find out for sure

Comment: It definitely wouldn't be as broad as the StackOverflow survey, nor would there be as much talent in publicizing/writing/graphic design. That being said, I won't rule it out

Comment: @W5VO If I proposed a survey, would the moderators be open to looking at it and possibly putting it up then?  I could find some spare time

Comment: @Funkyguy  Us mere diamond mods don't have control over what goes to the sidebar.  You could create a [community promotion ad](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/community-promotion-ads-2016), which can end up on the sidebar under favorable circumstances.

Comment: @NickAlexeev There is the [tag:featured] tag, which puts it in the same box (different heading) as the "Hot Meta Posts"

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks! I'll make one and post it on there.  Hopefully enough people upvote it

Comment: @Funkyguy If you want, we could set up a chat room for brainstorming, and then I can do what I can to make it show up for users.

Answer (score 4):

We're working on developing a survey. It's being done in our copious free time, so I can't promise a timeline for it. More will be posted when its ready.

Comment: Not sure if you have a specific direction for the survey but I would be very interested in any questions or discussion about what tools would make us more effective in our work. In software development, there are many new tools that change daily workflows of developers. I often feel that there are some holes to be filled there for EEs and would love to see if we can identify some major needs that we all share.